# Google Play Store Payments: Why Does Google Send Duplicate Notifications For SUBSCRIPTION_RENEWAL Payments?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-subscription, android-billing

I received these 7 notifications 5 seconds apart from each other.
Each `orderId` contains a suffixed "..X" where X increments with the number of notifications.

The `acknowledgementState` is also True immediately after the first notification. So I can not find any good reason why I have multiple notifications for this. My subscription model revolves on a monthly basis, so this shouldn't have happened naturally.

This is creating a problem for analytics, as we aren't sure how to address this. I dont think we can just strip the "..X" suffix and group the payments, because (by my knowledge) "..X" is supposed to indicate how many cycles the subscription has gone though. So there are legitimate reasons for it to show up and therefore can't be removed.

Any ideas on whats going on or how to appropriately handle it?

```
{'notificationType': 4,
 'orderId': 'GPA.3343-8735-0600-09134',
 'startTimeMillis': '1685532604363',
 'expiryTimeMillis': '1685532872944',
 'paymentState': 1,
 'acknowledgementState': 0,
 'purchaseType': 0}

{'notificationType': 2,
 'orderId': 'GPA.3343-8735-0600-09134..0',
 'startTimeMillis': '1685532604363',
 'expiryTimeMillis': '1685533172944',
 'paymentState': 1,
 'acknowledgementState': 1,
 'purchaseType': 0}

{'notificationType': 2,
 'orderId': 'GPA.3343-8735-0600-09134..1',
 'startTimeMillis': '1685532604363',
 'expiryTimeMillis': '1685533472944',
 'paymentState': 1,
 'acknowledgementState': 1,
 'purchaseType': 0}

{'notificationType': 2,
 'orderId': 'GPA.3343-8735-0600-09134..2',
 'startTimeMillis': '1685532604363',
 'expiryTimeMillis': '1685533772944',
 'paymentState': 1,
 'acknowledgementState': 1,
 'purchaseType': 0}

{'notificationType': 2,
 'orderId': 'GPA.3343-8735-0600-09134..3',
 'startTimeMillis': '1685532604363',
 'expiryTimeMillis': '1685534072944',
 'paymentState': 1,
 'acknowledgementState': 1,
 'purchaseType': 0}

{'notificationType': 2,
 'orderId': 'GPA.3343-8735-0600-09134..4',
 'startTimeMillis': '1685532604363',
 'expiryTimeMillis': '1685534372944',
 'paymentState': 1,
 'acknowledgementState': 1,
 'purchaseType': 0}

{'notificationType': 2,
 'orderId': 'GPA.3343-8735-0600-09134..5',
 'startTimeMillis': '1685532604363',
 'expiryTimeMillis': '1685534672944',
 'paymentState': 1,
 'acknowledgementState': 1,
 'purchaseType': 0}
```